# Using oracle loop to concatanete strings

Tags: oracle

I have someting like this
id day descrition

```
1  1   hi
1  1   today
1  1   is a beautifull
1  1   day
1  2   exemplo
1  2   for
1  2   this case
```

I need to do a funtion that for each day concatenate the descrtiomn colunm and return the result like this

```
id day descrition
1  1   hi today is a beautifull thay
1  2   exemplo for this case
```

Anny ideia about how can i do this usisng a loop in a function in oracle

Comment: You would need a column which can provide the ordering of words in each sentence.

Answer (score 0):

You need a way of determining which order the values should be aggregated. The snippet below will rely on the implicit order in which Oracle reads the rows from the datafiles - if you have row movement enabled then you may get inconsistent results as the rows can be read in different orders as they are relocated in the underlying datafiles.

```
SELECT LISTAGG( description, ' ' ) WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY ROWNUM ) AS description
FROM   your_table
GROUP BY id, day
```

It would be better to have another column that stores the order within each day.

Comment: this dos not work. i need have a ideia that i need to use a loop for because i'm doing it inside a funtion. For each id and each group of day concatenate the string.